# How to return all number of sentences instead of one?

Tags: python

I have a file contains several sentences, and I used polyglot for Named Entities, Now I want that all sentence (number) should be passed to another function step by step. But this function only returns one of the sentence numbers not all.

```py
def return_sentence_number():
    for i in range(len(file.sentences)):
        sentence_no = file.sentences[i]
        return sentence_no
```

if I print the file, it looks like:

```
print(file.sentences)
```

Output:

```
[Sentence("Ashraf Ghani president of Afghanistan"), Sentence("Bill Gates founder of Microsoft"), ....]
```

Expected Output:

Return the first, then second,... number of sentences to other function.

Comment: `return` is inside the for loop, so `return_sentence_number` returns the first `sentence_no`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you return from a function, the function stops execution because **return** means that the function has done it's job, so it gets terminated, there are two ways you can fix this.

1. Return a list

```py
def return_sentence_number():
    sentences = []
    for i in range(len(file.sentences)):
        sentence_no = file.sentences[i]
        sentences.append(sentence_no)
    return sentences

sentences = return_sentence_number() # contains a list 
# Iterate over values and do something
for sentence in sentences:
    pass
```

1a. Return a list using a list comprehension

```
def return_sentence_number():
    return [sentence_no for sentence_no in file.sentences]

sentences = return_sentence_number() # contains a list 
# Iterate over values and do something
for sentence in sentences:
    pass
```

2. Use Generators

```py
def return_sentence_number():
    sentences = []
    for i in range(len(file.sentences)):
        sentence_no = file.sentences[i]
        yield sentence_no

# Iterate over the generator and do something
for sentence in return_sentence_number(): 
    pass
```

Comment: Could you also show the use of a list comprehension to do the same job?

Comment: ```sentences = [file.sentences[i] for i in range(len(file.sentences))]```

Comment: Hmm, not quite. I'll update your answer with a list comprehension and then I'll be able to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Your return statement will return in the first iteration of your loop.

Maybe try using `yield`